# Need a Python package suitable for visualizing queue simulations

Tags: python, wxpython, visualization, simulation, scientific-computing

I am working on a simulation in Queueing Theory, within a wxPython GUI. ([Project link](http://garlicsim.org).) What would be a good tool for visualizing the simulations? The visualization should consist of simple objects, such as clients, servers, a facility and a population. They should all be represented by simple boxes or something like that. There will be several queues in which clients will wait.

Since this is a visualization of a progressing simulation, objects will move around the screen, and it would be nice if they could move smoothly from one place to another, and not jump abruptly.

What would be a good tool to create that visualization? I could do it in native wxPython graphics. I could also use PyGame. But maybe someone here has something better to recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [using **NS3**](http://www.nsnam.org/)?  It may be a little more than what you're looking for, but it is the standard for open source queue simulations.  Here's the documentation on [Python bindings for NS3](http://www.nsnam.org/wiki/index.php/NS-3_Python_Bindings).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of some 2D Graphics packages you might consider:

http://www.vrplumber.com/py3d.py?category=graphics

Answer (score 0):

wxPython has the OGL (Object Graphics Library) for doing this sort of thing.  I have not used it so I don't know how useful or robust it is, but it should be easier than using raw wx graphics primitives.

It is in wx.lib.ogl.

Comment: Checked it out, development is dead.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using one of the Python bindings for GraphViz. I could see something like this http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/cluster.html being used to illustrate a queue simulation.

I use Pydot and its gret:
http://code.google.com/p/pydot/

The only problem is that Pydot only writes the GraphViz files, you would have to use GraphViz itself or other renderer (such as Canviz http://www.ryandesign.com/canviz/) to obtain the graphics.

The advantage is that you just have to defined the structure of the graph and forget about time-consuming details such as line routing, drawing, etc.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using [VPython](http://vpython.org/).  You could also create a dynamic graphic in Java using [Processing](http://processing.org), and have the simulation send update messages through your network protocol of choice.